# how to remove/exclude html coding from json file while export?

Tags: jquery, array, json

I have created a file using json and exported it. Its creating HTML tags with it. Actually,I don't want to have that html part to be there in the file. Below I am sharing structure of my current file: HTML default tags like head,title etc and below is json alon with it.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="wp-toolbar"  lang="en-US">
<!--<![en-->
[{
    "ID" : 13,
    "post_author" : "1",
    "post_date" : "2015-10-30 07:09:16",
    "post_date_gmt" : "2015-10-30 07:09:16",
    "post_content" : "Test",
    "post_title" : "Test",
    "post_excerpt" : "",
    "post_status" : "publish",
    "comment_status" : "closed",
    "ping_status" : "closed",
    "post_password" : "",
    "post_name" : "test",
    "to_ping" : "",
    "pinged" : "",
    "post_modified" : "2015-10-30 07:09:16",
    "post_modified_gmt" : "2015-10-30 07:09:16",
    "post_content_filtered" : "",
    "post_parent" : 0,
    "guid" : "url/?post_type=wpcp_pointer&#038;p=9",
    "menu_order" : 0,
    "post_type" : "wpcp_pointer",
    "post_mime_type" : "",
    "comment_count" : "0",
    "filter" : "raw"
}
]
```

But what I want is :

```
[{
    "ID" : 13,
    "post_author" : "1",
    "post_date" : "2015-10-30 07:09:16",
    "post_date_gmt" : "2015-10-30 07:09:16",
    "post_content" : "Test",
    "post_title" : "Test",
    "post_excerpt" : "",
    "post_status" : "publish",
    "comment_status" : "closed",
    "ping_status" : "closed",
    "post_password" : "",
    "post_name" : "test",
    "to_ping" : "",
    "pinged" : "",
    "post_modified" : "2015-10-30 07:09:16",
    "post_modified_gmt" : "2015-10-30 07:09:16",
    "post_content_filtered" : "",
    "post_parent" : 0,
    "guid" : "url/?post_type=wpcp_pointer&#038;p=9",
    "menu_order" : 0,
    "post_type" : "wpcp_pointer",
    "post_mime_type" : "",
    "comment_count" : "0",
    "filter" : "raw"
}
]
```

Only JSON array to be there file export. Please help how could I remove that html part from json file. Below is the coding part using to generate this code:

```
$json_file = json_encode($need_options); // Encode data into json data
$json_file = stripslashes($json_file);

echo $json_file;

header("Content-Type: text/json; charset=" . get_option( 'blog_charset'));
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$json_name.json");
exit();
```

Any help will be really appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

You've left something out of the description-- namely, it isn't clear how/where you load that code. I am guessing you are pushing things through a template file somehow, or through a backend plugin file maybe, as you have what looks like template code showing up.

You should instead, in my opinion, be using the AJAX API:

```
function my_grab_ajax_wpse_108874() {
  if (empty($_GET['need_options'])) die;
  $need_options = $_GET['need_options']; // ??????
  $need_options = get_post($need_options);

  $json_name = $need_options->post_name;

  $json_file = json_encode($need_options); // Encode data into json data
  $json_file = stripslashes($json_file);

  header("Content-Type: text/json; charset=" . get_option( 'blog_charset'));
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$json_name.json");

  echo $json_file;

  exit();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_my_grab_ajax', 'my_grab_ajax_wpse_108874');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_grab_ajax', 'my_grab_ajax_wpse_108874');
```

Then request the data with `http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=mygrab_ajax&need_options={some post ID}`